# Sql LIKE statement. End Of String

Tags: t-sql

I have to select all fields which contain a specific text and ended with  `"`, `'`, `)` or blank space characters or this text is placed in the end of string.

So, I need something like that:

```
select *
from MyTable
Where Column1 like '%' + @text + '["'') ]%'
```

This query works fine until text is not placed in the end of `Column1`.

Comment: Could you give some simple input and desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use

```
Where Column1 + '"' like '%' + @text + '["'') ]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work better and faster:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE
   ( (RIGHT(Column1,1) IN (' ', '"', '''', ')'))
     AND
     (SUBSTRING(Column1, LENGTH(@text)-1, LENGTH(@text))=@text)
   ) 
OR ( RIGHT(Column1, LENGTH(@text))=@text )
```

Comment: The OP is looking for cases where the text is in the middle of the string but followed by one of the specified chars **or** at the right of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try OR?

```
 Where Column1 like '%' + @text + '["'') ]%'
  or
  Column1 like '%' + @text + '["'') ]'
```

Or do I misunderstand the requirement? Your question is a little hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    MyTable
WHERE   Column1 LIKE '%' + @text + '%["'') ]'
        OR Column1 LIKE '%' + @text
```