# Sql LIKE End Of String

Tags: sql, string, select, arcgis

I need to query all records of street addresses that end in a number.
For example, addresses that have the unit number at the end of the string:
"902 MILLBOURNE AVENUE -113"

Can someone please help me?

I found [Sql LIKE statement. End Of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790235/sql-like-statement-end-of-string) but am confused.

This is my attempt but there is an error with my expression:

```
SELECT * FROM AddressTable WHERE:
RIGHT(StreetAddress,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

---

Edit: 
I am using ArcGIS

Also, I was able to make a new field in my DB and populate it with the last character of the StreetAddress field and SQL select based on numeracy of that field (I used NewField IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')) to do that.
I would prefer to not make any schema changes, however.

Also, why are you down voting my question? Do you have an answer that will help me? Please Share it. If it doesn't work I dont know what else to tell you.

Comment: There should be no `:` after `WHERE`.

Comment: ArcGIS, and the first line is preset and cannot be changed by the program I am using. ':' is ok.

Comment: `there is an error with my expression` yes. and your DBMS is probably telling you what error, but for some reason you don't think it is relevant.

Comment: @user2375756 Are you using ArcGIS with another database or are you bound to the ArcGIS SQL subset?

Comment: You'll need to mention which database software you are using.

Comment: Post the entire error, please.

Comment: You want the entire error? LOL. 
It doesn't say any more that what I've already posted: 

See attached image. Whelp, can't post images so here it is : http://postimg.org/image/rkbowfbvp/

Answer (score 1):

There's no `:` after a `WHERE`. Fix your syntax like this:

```
SELECT * FROM AddressTable 
WHERE RIGHT(StreetAddress,1) IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9')
```

or you can use `LIKE` for a slightly more succinct query:

```
SELECT * FROM AddressTable WHERE StreetAddress LIKE '%[0123456789]'
```

Comment: OP here. 
The statement  does not return any results:
StreetAddress LIKE '%[0123456789]' 

I have addresses like the one above ^^:
 "902 MILLBOURNE AVENUE -113"
Even though your SQL statement doesn't work, wouldn't your expression select anything with a number after the first character?

Comment: `[0123456789]` can be written `[0-9]`

Comment: `LIKE` does not support ranges or regular expressions in SQL and the OP still hasn't specified which DBMS he/she is using.

Comment: @user2375756 `%` means any number of characters, and the expression matches the entire string, so because there is no trailing `%`, it matches the end of the string only.

Comment: @user2375756 I assume this is a limitation of ArcGIS, which I'm not familiar with. It works in standard SQL.

Comment: Yeah, good try, but it won't work. Arc doesn't tell you the problem with the query, just an invalid statement. It'

Comment: That's SQL Server syntax:  a standard `LIKE` does not interpret the character set in brackets.

Comment: Ah well, that may be why then. I wish there was a freely available version of the SQL standard.

Comment: Is there a way to multiple query numbers in a list without writing StreetAdress IS '%1' or StreetAdress '%2' or etcetc?